# elseif sql sever to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a trouble when i pass my stored procedure from SQL Server to MySql

[this is the original code from sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A67nR.jpg)

And this is my stored procedure from MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SelRutas`(CATEGORIA INT)
BEGIN

IF CATEGORIA = 1
    THEN
        select IdDepartamento AS Id, NombreDepartamento AS Nombre from DEPARTAMENTO;
    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 5
    THEN
        select ID_EVENTO AS Id, TITULO AS Nombre from EVENTO;   

    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 6
    THEN
        select IdGaceta AS Id, Titulo AS Nombre from Gaceta;        
    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 2
    THEN
        select IdApartado AS Id, Titulo AS Nombre from Apartados_;            
    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 3
    THEN
        select IdSubApartado AS Id, Titulo AS Nombre from SubApartados;     
    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 4
    THEN
        select ID_NOTICIA AS Id, NOTICIA_TITULO AS Nombre from NOTICIA;

    ELSE IF CATEGORIA = 7
    THEN
    select IdServicio AS Id ,Nombre AS Nombre from Servicios;        
END IF;        
End;
```

**↑The error is in the last line↑**

> Syntax Error: missing 'if'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ELSE IF` to `ELSEIF`

Documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html